# View on Click Listener in ListView Row Triggered On Multiple Rows

Tags: android, listview

i have a linear Layout that has a `OnClickListener`. the listener is working but its getting triggered on *multiple rows* (when going through the list, there are other rows that had the effect as well).

Here is my code for the `getView` in the `ArrayAdapter`.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final TaskRowHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new TaskRowHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);


        holder.audit_flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.audit_flag);
        holder.expandable = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        holder.camera_button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        holder.forms_button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.forms_button);
        holder.attachments_button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attachments_button);
        holder.label = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.functions_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.functions_layout);
        holder.expandable_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandabl_icon);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (TaskRowHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.expandable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (!holder.functions_layout.isShown())
            {
                holder.functions_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.expandable_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
                holder.label.setAnimation(null);
                holder.label.startAnimation(animationDown);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.functions_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.expandable_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
                holder.label.setAnimation(null);
                holder.label.startAnimation(animationDown);
            }
        }
    });
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: ListView is reusing row views, so that behavior is the expected behavior. You have to save somewhere positions of clicked rows, and in the `getView` apply changes to the view, if it has been clicked, and revert changes if it hasn't been clicked

Answer (score 0):

as @Vlad Matvienko commented, this is an expected behavior due to re-usability. i edited my code to the following.

```
ArrayList<String> expandablesClicked = new ArrayList<>();  //storing the row positions.

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final TaskRowHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new TaskRowHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);


        holder.audit_flag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.audit_flag);
        holder.expandable = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandable);
        holder.camera_button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
        holder.forms_button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.forms_button);
        holder.attachments_button = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attachments_button);
        holder.label = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        holder.functions_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.functions_layout);
        holder.expandable_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandabl_icon);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (TaskRowHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.expandable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {


            if (!expandablesClicked.contains(position+"")) //ADDED
            {
                expandablesClicked.add(position+"");  //ADDED
                holder.functions_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.expandable_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
                holder.label.setAnimation(null);
                holder.label.startAnimation(animationDown);
            }
            else
            {
                expandablesClicked.remove(position+""); //ADDED

                holder.functions_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.expandable_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
                holder.label.setAnimation(null);
                holder.label.startAnimation(animationDown);
            }
        }
    });

         //ADDED
        if (!expandablesClicked.contains(position+""))
        {
            holder.functions_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.expandable_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.functions_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

holder.expandable_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
            }
    .
    .
    .
    .

Answer (score 0):

If you want minimal hassle with required behavior mentioned by you(click only on one list row at a time), use [setOnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) instead of applying onClickListener on each view and checking multiple conditions. Implementation goes like-

```
yourlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
   @Override 
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);  //get your view restricted to your list row here and typecast to required layout.
   }  
});
```

**And yes, this will be called only on row which you click.**

Comment: this is for clicking on the ListVIew's row and not on a custom view inside the custom row's layout.

Comment: @rashad.z - Yes this is for listview row and not for custom view inside the custom row's layout. But ultimately you will handle individual view on each row click(as per question). This can be done with Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position); as well. Once you know position, you get the view and do whatever you want. So simple :) Handling onClick for each view will spoil the purpose of view holder if not optimized properly. Same can be done with solution I mentioned. Correct me if I am wrong. Or mention if any better solution is available.

Comment: this will make the first click on the row useless

Comment: @rashad.z - In that case, pls accept your answer :)